# Showing/hiding divs based on checkbox using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have a form with a checkbox (contained within a label `#contact`). For the change action of this checkbox, I am showing/hiding a div (`#options`).

To ensure that if the checkbox is checked the #options div always is always shown (and avoid the situation where checking the checkbox actually hides the subjequent options), I am using this code:

```
$('#contact :checkbox').is(':checked') ? $("#options").show() : $("#options").hide();
```

This works fine. The problem I have is that instead of a single checkbox with an ID, I want to have multiple checkboxes. I want to show/hide the next instance of my `.hidden` class based on whether the previous checkbox (within a label with the class `.trigger`) is checked or not. I have tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if( $('.trigger :checkbox').is(':checked') ) {
        $(this).parent().nextAll('ul.hidden').show();
    } else {
        $(this).parent().nextAll('ul.hidden').hide();
    }
});
```

But to no avail. The checkboxes are in an unordered list, like this:

```
<ul>
  <li><label class="trigger"><input type="checkbox" name="02" /> Trigger 1</label>
      <ul class="hidden">
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="02-sub1" /> Normal</label></li>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="02-sub2" /> Normal</label></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="02" /> Normal</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="03" /> Normal</label></li>
  <li><label class="trigger"><input type="checkbox" name="04" /> Trigger 2</label>
      <ul class="hidden">
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="04-sub1" /> Normal</label></li>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="04-sub2" /> Normal</label></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I can't see where I'm going wrong here; presumably my selector is incorrect, but I've played around with the syntax for ages and not got anywhere. Thanks in advance (and thank you for reading this far).

Comment: I've asked a followup question kind of related to this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470260/jquery-change-events-on-docready

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run your code inside a [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) handler, so `this` refers to the checkbox you want, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.trigger :checkbox').change(function() {
     if( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
       $(this).parent().nextAll('ul.hidden').show();
     } else {
       $(this).parent().nextAll('ul.hidden').hide();
     }
   });
});
```

...and that can be made much shorter with [`.toggle(bool)`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), like this:

```
$(function() {
   $('.trigger :checkbox').change(function() {
     $(this).parent().nextAll('ul.hidden').toggle(this.checked);
   });
});
```

If you need it to run when the page loads, so the show/hide states match the checkbox, just call that `change` handler with [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) (shortcut for [`.trigger('change')`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)), like this:

```
$(function() {
   $('.trigger :checkbox').change(function() {
     $(this).parent().nextAll('ul.hidden').toggle(this.checked);
   }).change();
});
```

Comment: Do you know how I can incorporate your function above (thank you by the way, it answers my initial question perfectly) with my current change function? I am having real problems getting them both to work.

Comment: @EdM - Honestly, I'd roll the question back to the original so it's a better resource, and ask your new/heavily modified question separately...as it stands an edit like this after answers are posted makes the question make very little sense to those finding it later.  Can you post a separate question and link it here, to keeps things a bit cleaner?

Comment: Ok, that sounds like a good idea thank you. Quite new to the site so it's useful to know the best way to go about things.

Answer (score 0):

You know you can roll your own fields, right? The typical way to do that is with a "rel=" field that has no meaning in HTML but can be picked up and used in jquery.

```
if ($('#contact :checkbox').is(':checked')) {
    $("#" + $('#contact :checkbox').attr('rel')).show();
} else {
    $("#" + $('#contact :checkbox').attr('rel')).hide();
}
```

And then:

```
  <li><label class="trigger"><input type="checkbox" name="04" rel="hidden-04" /> Trigger 2</label>
      <ul class="hidden" id="hidden-04">
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="04-sub1" /> Normal</label></li>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="04-sub2" /> Normal</label></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
```

So then, when the checkbox named 04 is checked, we look in its rel field for the id of the object to `hide()` or `show()`. I think that's a LOT easier than trying to walk the dom to find the target object.

Comment: This wouldn't work correctly, since `$('#contact :checkbox').attr('rel')` would return the *first* match's `rel` attribute...and the selectors repeated many times.  See my answer, doing this relatively is very easy :)

Comment: Hm. You're right--I was trying to work inside the code he had provided... The real solution (if you're going to do it this way; your post also solves his need) is to do this in the onClick handler bound to the :checkbox objects. Then you have a 'this' to talk about and you can get the rel attribute from that uniquely...