# jQuery change events on docready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to run part of a function when the page initially loads, but the majority of the `change` event should only run when the target is then subsequently interacted with.

The problem is that the two events are not unrelated - on page load I want to show certain divs, and then I want a click action that shows/hides the divs. I can get these two parts to run separately, but haven't been able to combine them.

My question is, what is the best way to achieve this separation? Is there a method in jQuery that says 'only run this part once' or 'run this part on page load, this part onclick'?

As an example, I have this code that loads on Docready (which uses `.change();` so that it runs immediately):

```
$(function() {
  $('.trigger :checkbox').change(function() {
    $(this).parent().nextAll('ul.hidden').toggle(this.checked);
  }).change();
});
```

But I alse want to run this code when someone clicks on one of my `.trigger` classes:

```
$('.trigger :checkbox').change(function() {
    var $target = $(this).parent().nextAll('.hidden'); // go up a level and then look for the next list with the hidden class
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');   // the class of the label needs to change, so find the parent of the checkbox
    $target.fadeToggle();
    if( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
        $target.find('.hidden').css('display', 'none'); // hide all submenus
    } else {
        $target.find(':checkbox').removeAttr('checked'); // untick all checkboxes in sub-menu if unchecking
    }                                                                                   
});
```

Currently, the click event gets very confused.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand what you want. Do you want to run some events when the page is loaded, and another event when an element is clicked? Like this http://jsfiddle.net/yg7f9/?

Comment: Kind of; my problem is that my change function(s) need to be applied to this same thing so I can make use of 'this'. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should split out the 'functionality' into functions and then call the different functions from the page load and the change event:

```
$(function() {

doSomething();

$("#selectElement").change(doSomething());

});

function doSomething() {}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've split it into two functions within my docready. What do I then need to add to get them to run as I want? I've put an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ed_melly/8Y89V/?