# Showing/Hiding Fields on checkbox event using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I tried to use [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462321/showing-hiding-divs-based-on-checkbox-using-jquery) as a guide, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with my below code. I'd appreciate it if someone could help out.

A little background: I have limited ability to change the HTML as it's in Confluence using an add-on called Confiforms. I can hide/show fields using Confiforms, but I generally find that it takes a performance hit when I configure it that way.

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td class="label editLabel">Customer Impact?</td>
    <td>
        <p class="auto-cursor-target">
            <span class="i_holdingrow_impact">
                <span id="i_holdingrow_impact">
                    <input cf-field="impact" class="radio" type="checkbox" name="impact" id="i_impact">
                </span>
            </span>
        </p>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td/>
    <td>
        <p>
            <span class="i_holdingrow_impactDesc">
                <span id="i_holdingrow_impactDesc">
                    <textarea cf-field="impactDesc" id="i_impactDesc" name="impactDesc" rows="4" class="textarea large-field cf_textarea"/>
                </span>
            </span>
        </p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Relevant jQuery:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(() => {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').show();
    }
    else {
        $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').hide();
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just a hunch, but if that table is loaded dynamically you might need to do event delegation `$('body').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"], () => {});`

Comment: So yeah, I definitely have that function to load after the table is loaded. It turned out the issue was with the arrow function. Arrow functions preserve `this` so it's no longer the relevant element I attached the event to (using the words of @Dekel). Changing it to `function() {...}` rather than `() => {...}` fixed my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be very careful when using jquery with arrow functions:

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').show();
    } else {
        $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').hide();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="label editLabel">Customer Impact?</td>
    <td>
        <p class="auto-cursor-target">
            <span class="i_holdingrow_impact">
                <span id="i_holdingrow_impact">
                    <input cf-field="impact" class="radio" type="checkbox" name="impact" id="i_impact">
                </span>
            </span>
        </p>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td/>
    <td>
        <p>
            <span class="i_holdingrow_impactDesc">
                <span id="i_holdingrow_impactDesc">
                    <textarea cf-field="impactDesc" id="i_impactDesc" name="impactDesc" rows="4" class="textarea large-field cf_textarea"></textarea>
                </span>
            </span>
        </p>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

> The arrow-function preserve the context of `this`, thus it's no longer the relevant element you attached the event to.

In case you do want to use arrow function, you can use the following:

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change((evt) => {
    el = evt.currentTarget;
    if ($(el).is(':checked')) {
        $(el).closest('tr').next('tr').show();
    } else {
        $(el).closest('tr').next('tr').hide();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="label editLabel">Customer Impact?</td>
    <td>
        <p class="auto-cursor-target">
            <span class="i_holdingrow_impact">
                <span id="i_holdingrow_impact">
                    <input cf-field="impact" class="radio" type="checkbox" name="impact" id="i_impact">
                </span>
            </span>
        </p>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td/>
    <td>
        <p>
            <span class="i_holdingrow_impactDesc">
                <span id="i_holdingrow_impactDesc">
                    <textarea cf-field="impactDesc" id="i_impactDesc" name="impactDesc" rows="4" class="textarea large-field cf_textarea"></textarea>
                </span>
            </span>
        </p>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow, I got so used to using arrow functions that I totally forgot about the preservation of this. I changed it to function() and it worked perfectly. Thanks Dekel!